# Java Applet and Storage Access

Tags: java, applet, japplet

We're developing an app that will be running embedded within a browser using secure sockets to communicate with a server. I want to add the ability for the applet to save its state (locally) so when they next open the page, the app can recall where the user was.

I've been looking into CookieManagers and Java Web Start with JNLP, but I'm unsure where to begin and what would be the best solution.

Any reccomendations? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished using self certification now. The user grants the application permission and then the application can read and write from the file system.

I used this article for signing the app: http://www.jade-cheng.com/uh/ta/signed-applet-tutorial/